# Inline-block displayed div are not on the same level

Tags: html, position, css

I have 4 divs displayed inside of a main container (a div) the trouble I have is that they are not on the same lever, some of them have a bigger text (1 line more), but the height is fixed to 100px so I guess it should have non incidence on there level.

But When I check the preview in the browser they are not displayed on the same level.

Below is a preview of what I get :

[image]

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```css
vertical-align: middle;
```

to the inner elements.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be dependend on the text length inside the las two divs.

Give every div a line more of height

Comment: all of this divs have height of 100px that's why I don't understand